# Selling an iOS App through non-AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, jailbreak

recently I was contacted by big Chinese publisher who has own "AppStore" on jailbroken devices. They offered me to sell my app through their platform too. 
I just wondering does anyone has an experience with that? Is it legal? Will Apple ban my app in AppStore?

I definitely don't want problems with Apple in future, but I remember some big companies were submitting their apps to the Cydia (but didn't sell same apps in AppStore...)

Comment: If it were my app, I wouldn't risk raising the ire of Apple, but your question is more of a philosophical one than a practical one.

Comment: It is quite practical, as it might be some license agreement violations. A tried to browse it briefly and didn't find, but I just might read too briefly.

Comment: I didn't think so that is it allowed by Apple

Comment: If you're doing well with Apple then I wouldn't risk it :)

Comment: And if you're not doing well with Apple, would you really do that much better elsewhere? (My impression is that you'd do better in the jailbreak market with apps that *can't* be sold in the App Store.)

Comment: @DavidDunham actually offer cam with very big chinese game portal (40+M users total, not in iOS). And they promise support with promotion, localization etc.. So, yes, it might be more successful than in AppStore. They told that they want to include my app in best kids bundle, so it looks very promising ;)

Comment: Could you tell me the name of this big company?

Comment: Company is netdragon, site is sj.91.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at, among other places, Section 7 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/41213383/iOS-Developer-Program-License-Agreement

> Applications developed under this Agreement may be distributed in two
>   ways: (1) through the AppStore, if selected by Apple, and (2)
>   distribution for use on a limited number of Registered Devices.

So distributing it any other way is a violation of your developer agreement (which is the only legit way to get the SDK) and grounds for terminating your developer agreement.